# Django ORM Foreignkey with two models

Tags: python, django, orm, foreign-keys

I am using Django and trying to relate two models with a basic one-to-many relation using a foreignkey. The models are,

```
class TopicModel(models.Model):
    topic = models.CharField(max_length=600
    # adding this line made it work
    topic_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

class PostModel(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    author = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    topic = models.ForeignKey(TopicModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

The view looks like,

```
def thread_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Tform = TopicForm(request.POST)
        Pform = PostForm(request.POST)
        if Tform.is_valid() and Pform.is_valid():
            tform = Tform.save(commit=False)
            tform.save()
            pform = Pform.save(commit=False)
            pform.topic = tform
            pform.author = request.user
            pform.pub_date = timezone.now()
            pform.save()
            return redirect('init')
    else:
        topicform = TopicForm()
        postform = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'new_topic.html', {'topicform': topicform, 'postform': postform})
```

Form is displaying fine, when I submit it, I get this error,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5nFJ.png)
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks

Here is forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Members, TopicModel, PostModel


class MemberForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # print 'this is the MemberForm'
    class Meta:
        model = Members
        # which fields to put in form
        fields = ('topic', 'post')

class TopicForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = TopicModel
        fields = ('topic',)

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PostModel
        fields = ('post',)
```

new_topic.html

```
{% extends 'index.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>New Topic Form</h1>
    <form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
        {{ topicform.as_p }}
        {{ postform.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show your forms?

Comment: Added more to the above, thanks for looking at it

Comment: It appears that you left topic field unfilled... is it so ?

Comment: Hi where is this that I left topic field unfilled?

Comment: Do you mean that every field in PostModel gets populated  by the form or the view except topic on PostModel? Thanks

Comment: When you submit the form is topic field filled ?

Comment: topic_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)

Comment: I added the above to the last line of the TopicModel and that is what made all the difference! It is working now

Comment: Well, in my opinion what you have done is not a proper way to do, especially topic_id field, you simply dont need it, plust PositiveIntegerField doesn't take null=True. It has to have a value, usually default=0.

Comment: Rajesh, Yes you are correct. I took out the topic_id and realised that the problem is the order in which things are happening in the view. So I rearranged the following two lines above like this. tform.save()
            pform = Pform.save(commit=False) and swapped them around. Thanks